# How to Configure the Web Connector from metrics.log Values

Tags: apache, coldfusion, tomcat7, coldfusion-10, mod-jk

I am reviewing the ColdFusion Web Connector settings in `workers.properties` to hopefully address a sporadic response time issue.

I've been advised to inspect the output from the `metrics.log` file (CF Admin > Debugging & Logging > Debug Output Settings > Enable Metric Logging) and use this to inform the adjustments to the settings `max_reuse_connections`, `connection_pool_size` and `connection_pool_timeout`.

My question is: How do I interpret the `metrics.log` output to inform the choice of setting values? Is there any documentation that can guide me?

Examples from over a 120 hour period:

95% of entries -

```
"Information","scheduler-2","06/16/14","08:09:04",,"Max threads: 150 Current thread count: 4 Current thread busy: 0 Max processing time: 83425 Request count: 9072 Error count: 72 Bytes received: 1649 Bytes sent: 22768583 Free memory: 124252584 Total memory: 1055326208 Active Sessions: 1396"
```

Occurred once -

```
"Information","scheduler-2","06/13/14","14:20:22",,"Max threads: 150 Current thread count: 10 Current thread busy: 5 Max processing time: 2338 Request count: 21 Error count: 4 Bytes received: 155 Bytes sent: 139798 Free memory: 114920208 Total memory: 1053097984 Active Sessions: 6899"
```

Environment:

- 3 x Windows 2008 R2 (hardware load balanced)
- ColdFusion 10 (update 12)
- Apache 2.2.21

Answer (score 0):

Richard, I realize your question here is from 2014, and perhaps you have since resolved it, but I suspect your problem was that the port set in the CF admin (below the "metrics log" checkbox) was set to 8500, which is your internal web server (used by the CF admin only, typically, if at all). That's why the numbers are not changing. (And for those who don't enable the internal web server at installation of CF, or later, most values in the metrics log are null).

I address this problem in a blog post I happened to do just last week: http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2016/3/2/cf_metrics_log_part1

Hope any of this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up Charlie. I no longer have access to this project so can't check your suggestion. As it happens you helped us get to the root of the problem which was the web connector `workers.properties` `max_reuse_connections` _"too small"_ issue.